# Kubernetes deployment error with Java/Micronaut: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, netty

I am trying to deploy an app having 3 services - frontend (Angular), backend 1 (Java/Micronaut), and backend 2 (Java/Micronaut).

My frontend works properly but the Java apps are not working.

Sometimes, I observed it started after 20 min. of deploying a Java app, but this time it does not work even after 1 hr.

Deployment, pod service - all are in running state in Kubernetes, but when I try to hit the URL I see below error:

[image]

> deployment.yaml for java app

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: authentication-deploy
  labels:
    name: authentication-deploy
    app: supply-chain-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: authentication-pod
      app: supply-chain-app

  template:
    metadata:
      name: authentication-pod
      labels:
        name: authentication-pod
        app: supply-chain-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: authentication
          image: cawishika/authentication-service:1.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

> service.yaml for java app

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: authentication-service
  labels:
    name: authentication-service
    app: supply-chain-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30006
  selector:
    name: authentication-pod
    app: supply-chain-app
```

> Docker file

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest
EXPOSE 8002
ADD target/authentication-service-0.1.jar authentication-service-0.1.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/authentication-service-0.1.jar"]
```

kubectl logs podname
[image]

Comment: "Connection refused" == client can't connect, because the service isn't running. It sounds like the "service" in question is probably an HTTP web server that's supposed to be running on your Docker instance(s).  The *instance* is running, the *host* is accessible on the network ... but the *service* - for whatever reason - isn't running on that instance.  Troubleshoot from there.  For example, look at the instance's log files.

Comment: you mean kubectl logs podname?

Comment: added an image for logs too, looks ok to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: server running]

Your Dockerfile is exposing port `8002` (`EXPOSE 8002`), but your app is started on port `8080`.

Additionally, your Kubernetes configuration is pointing to port `80` of your pod.

You should set it so that all three configurations use the same port.